# df.loc not outputting anything

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file (Pre-Generated with all the values) that looks something like this:

| itemName | itemBrand | itemCode | itemStock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SomeName | SomeBrand | 6-Digits | SomeNumber |
| And | it | continues | further |

And here it is `for row in file: print`ted out:

```
['itemname1', 'itembrand1', '993770', '17'] 
[] 
['itemname2', 'itembrand2', '968188', '4'] 
[] 
['itemname3', 'itembrand3', '222592', '19'] 
[] 
['itemname4', 'itembrand4', '935887', '2']
[]
```

My code to edit it is as follows:

```py
def edit_item(itemCode, newNetStock, editDate):
    df = pandas.read_csv(main_db)
    oldStockTemp = df[df['itemCode']==itemCode]
    oldStock = str(oldStockTemp['itemStock'].values).strip("[]")
    newStock = oldStock + newNetStock
    df.loc[df["itemCode"] == itemCode, "itemStock"] = newStock
    df.to_csv(main_db, index=False)
    return "finished"
    # Below this is commented out as its verified working.
    # with open(itemCode + ".csv", mode='a') as file:
        # logger = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        # logger.writerow([editDate, newItemStock])
```

It does not output anything, the .csv status the same. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please show the contents of your csv data file (a few lines are enough) as text ? The formatted table is nice, but it doesn't show the separator. Your code works for me with the comma as separator (and after casting `int(oldStock)` when adding it).

Comment: `['itemname1', 'itembrand1', '993770', '17']
[]
['itemname2', 'itembrand2', '968188', '4']
[]
['itemname3', 'itembrand3', '222592', '19']
[]
['itemname4', 'itembrand4', '935887', '2']
[]`
That what came out then I did `for row in file: print(row)`
Edited: formatting

Comment: @joao Edited the post as the formatting is not great on the comments

Comment: If that's the entire contents of the csv file, then you don't have headers, and you should be getting `KeyError: 'itemCode'`. Are you getting any error messages ? And how are you calling the `edit_item` function ?

Comment: @joao Yup I noticed the headers, my bad. I tried again and still got no change. I'm running it by importing it and running it through a PyQt GUI.

Comment: You are importing and running what exactly ? You haven't shown the code that calls your `edit_item` function, that's what I was asking about.

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, people here might not use PyQt (I don't), so make sure to reproduce your problem when running your script simply as `python myscript.py` in a shell, which is what people here will be doing.